# Extending flan-t5 on custom rest api's

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

Can I extend flan-t5 to use custom rest api's as described in: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/apis ?

I've tried doing this with langchain and llama and didn't work out (out of the box)

I expected llm other that gpt to be able and manipulate langchain agents in order to use rest api's, given their description